# Is there any connection between Paris of Troy and Paris of Verona?

Tags: william-shakespeare, name-significance, homer, the-iliad, romeo-and-juliet

I just noticed that a character in Shakespeare's *Romeo and Juliet* has the same name as a character in Homer's *Iliad*: **Paris.** In both stories, Paris is one of two men who wish to be with the same woman; Paris of Troy elopes with an already married woman, while Paris of Verona is engaged to marry a woman already in love with someone else. In both stories, Paris ends up dead at the hands of an enemy.

**Is there any evidence that this is more than a coincidence?** I've provided some circumstantial evidence, but I don't know much about Shakespeare's sources for the story of Romeo and Juliet, whether earlier versions also featured Paris and whether he always had that name, or indeed whether *those* stories in turn could potentially be traced back to Homer. It's clear at least that Shakespeare knew the story of the *Iliad*, as can be seen from his play *Troilus and Cressida*.

Comment: This question could do with at least 9 tags: [tag:william-shakespeare], [tag:romeo-and-juliet], [tag:the-iliad], [tag:homer], [tag:greek-literature], [tag:character-analysis], [tag:inspiration], [tag:name-significance], [tag:intertextuality]. I've added what I hope are the 5 most useful.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned [elsewhere](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/9018/2191), Shakespeare's main sources for *Romeo and Juliet* were

- Arthur Brooke's narrative poem [The Tragical History of Romeus and Juliet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tragical_History_of_Romeus_and_Juliet) (1562) and
- [William Painter's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Painter_(author)) prose version of the story in the second volume of *The Palace of Pleasure* (1567).

There is no evidence that Shakespeare read any of the French or Italian sources for this story, such as [Pierre Boaistuau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Boaistuau) or [Matteo Bandello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandello).

An older version of the story that Bandello used was [Luigi Da Porto's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Da_Porto) *Historia novellamente ritrovata di due nobili amanti* ("Newly found story of two noble lovers"), published in 1531. In this version, Giulietta's father wants her to marry the **Count of Lodrone**.

Another version of the story was published in Venice in 1553; this was a poem entitled *L'Infelice Amore dei due Fedelissimi Amanti Giulia e Romeo, scritto in Ottava Rima da Clitia, nobile Veronese, ad Ardeo suo*. Who Clitia (the author) and her Ardeo were is unknown. In this version of the story, the Count of Lodrone is known as **Francesco**.

In Bandello's version of the story, published in 1554, the Count of Lodrone / Conte di Lodrone is now for the first time named **Paris**. (Bandello was also the first author to add Juliet's nurse to the story.) I have not been able to find out why Bandello chose Paris as a name.

Pierre Boaistuau or Boisteau seems to have kept the name of Paris in his French version of Bandello's stories, *Histoires Tragiques extraictes des Œuvres de Bandel* (1559).

The name Lodrone is no longer present in Arthur Brooke's narrative poem [The Tragical History of Romeus and Juliet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tragical_History_of_Romeus_and_Juliet) (1562), but it is interesting that the first mention of Paris does not refer to the Count but to the [character from Homer's *Iliad*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_(mythology)):

> At length he [Romeus] saw a maid, right fair, of perfect shape,
>   Which Theseus or Paris would have chosen to their rape.

("Rape" here has the older meaning of "to carry off", as in [The Rape of the Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rape_of_the_Lock). Theseus was also ["a great abductor of women"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theseus#The_abduction_of_Persephone_and_encounter_with_Hades).)

Count Paris is introduced much later:

> Among the rest was one inflamed with her desire,
>   Who County Paris clepéd was; an earl he had to sire.
>   Of all the suitors him the father liketh best,

In Brooke's poem, Romeus does not encounter Paris at the Capulet tomb; Paris survives until the end.

The connection between Paris of Troy and Count Paris is not a simply a parallel, since a number of things are reversed in Shakespeare's play:

- Paris of Troy has no right to abduct Helen, who is married to Menelaus.
- From a "public" point of view (i.e. what the Capulet household knows), Count Paris is a perfectly suitable match for Juliet.
- However, Juliet has secretly married Romeo, so the private or secret here clashes with the public point of view.
- Whereas Brooke mentions both Paris of Troy and Count Paris, Shakespeare does not mention Paris of Troy. (Helen is mentioned by Mercutio in [Act II, scene 4](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/romeo_juliet.2.4.html) and a certain "lively Helena" is on the guest list for the Capulet party in [Act I, scene 2](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/romeo_juliet.1.2.html). However, Helen is a not an unusual name in Shakespeare's plays: there is also a Helen in *A Midsummer Night's Dream*, *All's Well That Ends Well* and obviously in *Troilus and Cressida*. Helen of Troy is also mentioned in other plays, such as *As You Like It*, *Henry VI Part 3* and *Henry IV Part 2*.)
- There is indeed a parallel between Paris of Troy and Shakespeare's Count Paris in that both die. I am not aware of evidence that Homer's *Iliad* gave Shakespeare this idea. Rivalry between men who love the same woman is a common theme in Shakespeare's plays, from the early *The Two Gentlemen of Verona* to the late *The Two Noble Kinsmen*.

Comment: Upvoted for good research and info, but I probably won't accept this unless you can find some more conclusive evidence one way or the other (which I realise may not actually exist). Agreed that the similarities between the characters are far from exact, and "*Rivalry between men who love the same woman is a common theme in S̶h̶a̶k̶e̶s̶p̶e̶a̶r̶e̶'̶s̶ ̶p̶l̶a̶y̶s̶ literature*" :-)